# Attribute table width and line breaks

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, print-composer

When the cell's width of an attribute table containing text/string is modified to a number of mm, it automatically adds a line break on the last word.

**Example**

[image: exemple]

*The red ellipse shows the last word*

**Steps**

1. Open Print Composer;
2. Add Attribute Table;
3. In "Item properties" tab, click "Attributes..." button and change the cell's width from *Automatic* to 100mm for example;

Is there a way to fix this issue? Maybe with sql?

**Observations**

This problem doesn't seem related to the layer datatype (shapefile, geopackage, ...)

Comment: Can you provide an example of this issue?

Comment: Can you post a example of the data. Remember that it is not possible tot have text data in a numericcolumn.

Comment: Having the same issue right now. Any progress on this in the last year?

Comment: @Isaacson, no progress... the same problem appears on QGIS 3.4